# How to send topic messages through firebase console?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send news messages to all app users. I thought about using Firebase Cloud Messaging. It is implemented on the client (Android app) and registered for a topic. Now I would like to send a message through the Firebase Console to this topic.

Is this possible? And how can I send a firebase message to a specific topic using the firebase console? I searched on the website, but did not find the option. Or is this only possible using a script (e.g. PHP) to send a message to a specific topic.

Comment: I still see the option to Send to a Topic in the second step of the Notifications composer page in the Firebase console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HpHd.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Notification composer](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/notification/compose) of the Firebase console, enter a title and text for your message.

[image]

Then click <kbd>Next</kbd>.

In the next page, click the <kbd>Topic</kbd> button to send the message to a topic:

[image]